# Getting import gtk.glade in Python to work on windows

Tags: windows, gtk, pygtk, glade

I am trying to get a Python program designed and run on Linux to run on Windows. I have been hunting down each libraries required but got stuck on `import gtk.glade` right now. (The code that calls glade loads an .glade file for GUI layout.)

Anyone knows how to get gtk.glade on Windows? Is this a version problem? i got pygtk setup through the first 5 steps listed at http://www.gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=Windows_installer#Dependencies_-_The_hard_way